# Postgresql last value of column while using aggregate functions

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following working query:

```
select children.autor as child,  parents.autor as parent, count(*) from comments children
left join comments parents on (children.parentid = parents.commentid)
group by child, parent
order by count(*) desc
limit 4;
```

which produces following output:

```
    child           |       parent        | count
peter               | max                 |   154
alex                | peter               |   122
peter               | kARL                |    82
stephen             | alex                |    50
```

Now the comments table also has a column 'bodytext' that is the actual comment and I want to include the last comment in the selection for each pair of child and parent.

So in the first line I want the last comment that peter wrote in reply to max.
So far I don't even know how to approach this. A subquery? Some sort of window function?

If I use (max)bodytext, it almost does exactly what I want.. just the longest comment which is not really want I want.

Comment: Do each of the comments have any incremental `id` field? If so, you might just select the comment body with the max `id` out of all the comments that `peter` wrote `max`. I'll give it a shot later if you're still having issues as I'm a bit short on time at the moment.

Comment: Yes each comment has an incremental id.

Answer (score 12):

**Add just this 1 line to your select:**

```
(array_agg(children.bodytext ORDER BY children.commentid DESC))[1] AS last_comment
```

It will create an array of all the comments for every group, comments will be ordered as specified (by children.commentid DESC), and then you take just the 1st element of the array = the last comment.

**Whole code:**

```
SELECT
  children.autor AS child,
  parents.autor AS parent,
  count(*),
  (array_agg(children.bodytext ORDER BY children.commentid DESC))[1] AS last_comment
FROM
  comments AS children
  LEFT JOIN comments AS parents
    ON (children.parentid = parents.commentid)
GROUP BY child, parent
ORDER BY count(*) DESC;
```

Comment: This works as intended. Can I understand array_agg as way to create your "custom" aggregate function? Is the [1] at the end limit 1? Thanks!

Comment: @Alex `array_agg` is an aggregate function that creates an array from a  specific field of all the records selected. [1] is array notation to get the first item in the array (PG array indexing starts at 1 rather than 0). Since you can put a sort order in `array_agg`, what the above does is create an array of `bodytext` ordered by `commentid` DESC, then gets the first item in that array.

Comment: I found a lot of complexity in other solutions (not just on this question). This was the answer I was searching for, ans should be the correct one. Thanks man!

Comment: The only drawback of this answer is that it passes over the table more than once, so performance-wise it's not exactly ideal. But it's also _much_ more readable!

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for that one liner with explanation.
Used it in quite a different and much more complex scenario, but after disecting it the proper place to put it - it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

There are two approaches to this.  One uses window/analytic functions, particularly `first_value()`.  The other uses arrays.

An example of the first approach:

```
select distinct c.autor as child,  cp.autor as parent,
       count(*) over (partition by c.autor, cp.autor) as cnt,
       first_value(c.bodytext) over (partition by c.autor, cp.auto order by ? desc)
from comments c left join
     comments cp
     on c.parentid = cp.commentid
order by cnt desc
limit 4;
```

The `?` is for the column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: This also works as intended. I guess "partition by partition by" is simply a typo. I remove the second partition by. Either my dataset (400.000) is too small or the solution is about as fast as the one by Joe Samanek. Thanks!

Comment: This is probably more efficient than array_agg because there could be a lot of text to agg

Answer (score 0):

This should do it if `commentid` is in chronological order. Your query, with `max(c.commentid)` added to it, is called `query1` here and then used in an outer query where the last `bodytext` is joined in:

```
with query1 as (
  select c.autor child, p.autor parent, count(*) cnt, max(c.commentid) id_last
  from       comments c
  left join  comments p on p.commentid=c.commentid
  group by c.autor, p.autor
)
select q.child, q.parent, q.cnt, t.bodytext comment_last
from      query1   q
left join comments t on t.commentid = q.id_last
order by t.cnt desc
limit 4;
```

Not sure if the `left`s are needed. Depends on your data and what you want. *(And btw, autor should perhaps be written author)*

Answer (score 0):

Assume the latest `bodytext` has the highest `commentid`. Use window function `FIRST_VALUE` to get the latest `bodytext` and `COUNT` to get the count for within each group of child/parent. Use `DISTINCT` to eliminate the duplicates.

```
select distinct child, parent, 
first_value(bodytext) over (partition by child, parent order by commentid desc) bodytext,
count(*) over (partition by child, parent ) count
from
(select children.autor as child,  parents.autor as parent, children.bodytext, children.commentid 
from comments children
left join comments parents on (children.parentid = parents.commentid )) t
order by count desc
limit 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only retrieving 4 rows, a subquery should do fine here, as it should only be evaluated for the rows fetched.

```
select children.autor as child,  parents.autor as parent, count(*),
  (select bodytext
   from comments
   where commentid = max(child.commentid)) as last_comment
from comments children
left join comments parents on (children.parentid = parents.commentid)
group by child, parent
order by count(*) desc
limit 4;
```